# TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined at Module.extractRequires [as _extractor]

Tags: npm, react-native

#### Description

I recently upgraded my react-native package and some others in my package.json to the latest release. Each time I try to compile me project, I run into a this error in the terminal:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at Module.extractRequires [as _extractor] (PATH_TO_PROJECT/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/node-haste/lib/extractRequires.js:31:10)
    at codePromise.then.result (PATH_TO_PROJECT/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/node-haste/Module.js:209:49)
    at tryCallOne (PATH_TO_PROJECT/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at PATH_TO_PROJECT/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
    at flush (PATH_TO_PROJECT/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)`

The simulator throws the following error:

`{"type":"InternalError","message":"react-packager has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details"}`

I can't tell if this is a source code problem, or if I messed up somehow in updating my npm packages.

#### Additional Information

- React Native version: 0.39.2
- Platform: iOS
- Operating System: MacOS

Comment: please add some relevant code

Comment: I would, but the stacktrace leads only to code in the npm packages